# Javascript - show a button inside of a DIV when clicked (and hide all others)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of DIVS that have buttons inside. By default, all buttons are hidden. When I click within a DIV area, the current button inside of this clicked DIV are should show (class='.db') AND all previously clicked/shown buttons should be hidden (class='.dn'). In other words, at any time there should be only one button (currently clicked) shown and all other should be hidden.

I want to use vanilla Javascript and tried this below, but it won't work. I feel there is some small error but don't know where.. Note - the DIVS and buttons don't have their own unique IDs (they only have the same CSS (.posted) classes.

PS - maybe it'd be better not to add this onClick="t();" to each DIV and use an 'addEventListener' function, but this is way too much for me ; )

---

**CSS:**

```
.dn {display:none}
.db {display:block}
.posted {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="posted" onClick="t();">
<button class="dn">Reply</button>
</div>

<div class="posted" onClick="t();">
<button class="dn">Reply</button>
</div>

<div class="posted" onClick="t();">
<button class="dn">Reply</button>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function t()
{
var x=document.getElementsByClassName("posted"),i,y=document.getElementsByTagName("button");

for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
x[i].y[0].className="dn";
};

x.y[0].className='db';//make sure the currently clicked DIV shows this button (?)
}
```

Comment: u need to do it just in js or use jquery. JQuery can make ur work easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to read more about selector, how to select class, block level etc.

some link might be helpful:

CSS selector:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

jQuery selector:

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

### Solution - Using jQuery:

```js
$('.posted').on('click', function() {
  //find all class called posted with child called dn, then hide them all
  $('.posted .dn').hide();
  //find this clicked div, find a child called dn and show it
  $(this).find('.dn').show();
});
```

```css
.dn {
  display: none
}

.db {
  display: block
}

.posted {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="posted">
  <button class="dn">Reply1</button>
</div>

<div class="posted">
  <button class="dn">Reply2</button>
</div>

<div class="posted">
  <button class="dn">Reply3</button>
</div>
```

### Solution - Pure js version:

```js
//get list of div block with class="posted"
var divlist = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('posted'));

//for each div
divlist.forEach(function(item) {
  //add click event for this div
  item.addEventListener("click", function() {
    //hide all button first
    divlist.forEach(function(el) {
      el.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].classList.add('dn');
    });
    //show button of the div clicked
    this.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].classList.remove('dn');
  }, false);
});
```

```css
.dn {
  display: none
}

.db {
  display: block
}

.posted {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="posted">
  <button class="dn">Reply1</button>
</div>

<div class="posted">
  <button class="dn">Reply2</button>
</div>

<div class="posted">
  <button class="dn">Reply3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If it was pure JS I'd be totally delighted :)

Comment: @Tom ok got the pure js one for you

Comment: I almost gave up since it didn't work at first (it works with no elements within div but when there is some text the children[0] didn't target the button). So I changed children[0] to getElementsByTagName('button')[0] and it works now, thank you!

Comment: @Tom Cool, good to know. I updated too in case it could help others too. thanks for the note

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with with plain JavaScript using Event Bubbling, `querySelector` and the element `classList` attribute like this.

Change your HTML to look like this:

```
<div class="posts">
    <div class="posted">
        <button class="dn">Reply</button>
    </div>

    <div class="posted" >
        <button class="dn">Reply</button>
    </div>
    <div class="posted" >
        <button class="dn">Reply</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Then use JavaScript like this:

```
var posts = document.querySelector('.posts');
var allPosted = document.querySelectorAll('.posted');

//clicks bubble up into the posts DIV
posts.addEventListener('click', function(evt){
    var divClickedIn = evt.target;
    //hide all the buttons
    allPosted.forEach(function(posted){
        var postedBtn = posted.querySelector('button');
        postedBtn.classList.remove('db');
    });

    // show the button in the clicked DIV
    divClickedIn.querySelector('button').classList.add('db')
});
```

You can find a working example here: http://output.jsbin.com/saroyit

Answer (score 0):

Here is very simple example using jQuery `.siblings` method:

```
$(function () {

    $('.posted').click(function () {

        $('button', this).show();
        $(this).siblings().find('button').hide();
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3tg6o1q7/